# PHP SQL order by other table

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-order-by

I want to be able to order the list from the inner select from the database. My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from `users` WHERE `name` in (select `last` from info where `date` = '2013' ORDER BY  `id` DESC)";
```

I want to be able to get the order from table `last` instead of `users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Use `JOIN` query

```
$sql = "SELECT u.* from `users` u JOIN `info` i ON u.name = i.last WHERE i.date = '2013' ORDER BY i.id DESC";
```